# Applying two different transforms to a message coming in from off-ramp and sending the output of each transform to a different off ramp extender

Tags: biztalk, esb

I have a message being received as a response on an off-ramp. I need to apply two different transforms on this message (no filter required) and send the output of each of the transforms to a different off-ramp.

So basically, my itinerary looks like the following:

On-Ramp --> Messaging Extender (Transform) --> Off-Ramp Extender --> Off-Ramp --> [Here I need to transform the received response to two different messages and send each one to a different Off-Ramp]

I have tried a few approaches but have not been successful. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Ruchitra

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of approaches:

- Create an orchestration which sequentially processes the response in each of the two ways
- [Write the response to the message box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa949234.aspx) then create two send ports (with a filter so they will only process the response). This option will let you stop processing to one off ramp without affecting the other.